# How do you measure global UI experience

Tags: experience

How can we measure if our UI is suited for global markets? When you're present in 22 countries with very different user experiences and demands, what is the metric which indicates if our UI needs to be reviewed?

Comment: Do you have a _metric_ for each single country? Do you have an _internal metric_?

Comment: You need to research every single implementation and then decide if the UX is good or bad. The easiest way is if you have Analytics in all of them, and just check for differences between the 22 implementations. There is no shortcut, it need some good work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cultural Appropriateness

It sounds like what you're talking about is **cultural appropriateness** - are the colors correct? (red means power and money in China, and means danger in the west), is the tone of the translation correct? (perhaps the use of the imperative in CTAs e.g. Buy Now! is inappropriate), are the images and graphics used consistent with what users in that region expect (Eastern wed design is vector graphic heavy, whereas the western design utilizes photographic elements more)

This a very basic approach, but would be a good start point nonetheless.

**Heuristic Evaluation with local experts**

Have someone who is native to and located in a region (perhaps a local marketing rep for your company, or hire a local designer) to evaluate where your site or app falls short of what local users might expect. Your really just looking for red flags. Glaring issues.

**User Testing with local users**

Once you've made implemented their feedback, and get their input. You could ask generic questions like "Does this look like a [name of region] web site? Does the design of this website make you trust the company more, or less?" or more specific questions that relate to the specific changes you made.

Comment: +1 to balance out the -1. This is a good answer to a very broad question.